# Geoserver MapFish plugin: absolutely positioning scale bar

Tags: geoserver, mapfish

I have a map printed full page on A4 paper. I would like to put a scalebar over the map without printing in on the next page. Is it possible? My config.yaml currently looks like this:

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------
mainPage:
  pageSize: A4
  marginBottom: 0
  marginTop: 0
  rotation: true
  items:
    - !map
      spacingAfter: 0
      width: 595
      height: 842
    - !scalebar
      type: bar
      maxSize: 100
      barBgColor: white
      fontSize: 8
      align: right
    - !text
      font: Helvetica
      fontSize: 9
      align: right
      text: '1:${scale}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working

```
mainPage:
  pageSize: A4
  marginBottom: 0
  marginTop: 0
  rotation: true
  items:
    - !map
      spacingAfter: 0
      width: 595
      height: 832
    - !columns
      widths: [200, 200]
      absoluteX: 40
      absoluteY: 45
      width: 595
      items:
        - !scalebar
          align: left
          backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'
          fontsize: 9
          type: bar
          units: km
          barSize: 5
          intervals: 3
          maxSize: 200
          fontSize: 10            
        - !text
          text: '© ENVIPARTNER, s.r.o. 2009-2014'
          align: center
    - !columns
      widths: [150]
      absoluteX: 40
      absoluteY: 65
      width: 595
      fontsize: 9
      items:
        - !text
          text: '1:${scale}'
```